# Redirect conflicting and not redirecting the correct URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Need your guidance. i am stuck with permanent redirection via .htaccess in WordPress. I Went through many post on SF but were not up to mark.

**Scenario :**

1. i have 2 domains
2. both domains host same content but on different URL like; old-domain/apple = new-domain/apl

**Requisite :**

1. every URL on Old-domain.com should be redirected to New-domain.Net; as i wish means, i will decide which URL from previous domain should redirect to which url on new domain. This should no way be automatically done. There may be chances that i can point two or more URL of old domain to a particular URL on new-domain.
2. if a particular page or URL etc whatever it may be, is not found on old-domain then it should be redirected to New-domain.
3. there are few URL that doesn't exist on old-domain any more. with SEO point of view, i would like to redirect them as well on new-domain.
  4.

This is what i got closest to doing what i wish.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
**redirect 301 /apple http://newdomain.com/apl
redirect 301 /colour http://newdomain.com/color**
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But this set of codes does not work proper with my blog. instead it start to redirect old-domain/wp-admin/edit/php automatically to new-domain/wp-admin/edit/php

**Looking for :**

i am looking for perfect codes that can help me doing this. just do a demonstration on how to proceed with some fictitious domain name n url, so that i can understand and do my domains.

Thanks

Comment: Try placing this rule `RewriteRule ^apple/?$ http://newdomain.com/apl [R=301,L]` right after the `RewriteBase /` and tell me if it works as you expect, if it does not then I am afraid you have it conflicting with either another .htaccess file or an issue with the newdomain htaccess file.

Comment: i don’t know what i did, or didn't on old-domain. where as new-domain is concern. i haven't done anything to it. my old-domain .htaccess file was too messy because of cache plugin.  

secondly i didn't get what you are trying to tell me. if you don't mind. make me a whole new .htaccess file. i will appreciate if you TML5  

forgot to mention, above shown is actual text from my htaccess file, except 2 redirect shown as examples.